# Understanding deeply spliterator characteristics

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spliterator

In order to try to deeply understand java streams and spliterators,  I have some subtle questions about **spliterator characteristics**:

**Q1: `Stream.empty()` vs `Stream.of()`** (Stream.of() without args)

- `Stream.empty()`: *SUBSIZED, SIZED*
- `Stream.of()`:    *SUBSIZED, **IMMUTABLE**, SIZED, **ORDERED***

Why `Stream.empty()` doesn't have the same characteristics of `Stream.of()`? Note that it has impacts when using in conjunction with Stream.concat() (specially not having `ORDERED`). I would say that `Stream.empty()` should have not just *IMMUTABLE and ORDERED* but also *DISTINCT and NONNULL*. Also it make sense `Stream.of()` with only one argument having *DISTICT*.

**Q2: `LongStream.of()` not having *NONNULL***

Just noticed that NONNULL is not available in `LongStream.of`.
Isn't `NONNULL` a main characteristics of all `LongStream`s, `IntStream`s and `DoubleStream`s?

**Q3: `LongStream.range(,)` vs `LongStream.range(,).boxed()`**

- `LongRange.range(,)`: *SUBSIZED, **IMMUTABLE, NONNULL**, SIZED, ORDERED, **SORTED, DISTINCT***
- `LongStream.range(,).boxed()`: *SUBSIZED, SIZED, ORDERED*

Why `.boxed()` loses all these characteristics? It shouldn't lose any.

I understand that `.mapToObj()` can lose the *NONNULL, IMMUTABLE and DISTICT*, but `.boxed()`... doesn't make sense.

**Q4: `.peek()` loses *IMMUTABLE and NONNULL***

`LongStream.of(1)`: *SUBSIZED, IMMUTABLE, NONNULL, SIZED, ...*
`LongStream.of(1).peek()`: *SUBSIZED, SIZED, ...*

Why `.peek()` loses these characteristics? `.peek` shouldn't really lose any.

**Q5: `.skip()`, `.limit()` loses *SUBSIZED, IMMUTABLE, NONNULL, SIZED***

Just notice that these operations loses *SUBSIZED, IMMUTABLE, NONNULL, SIZED*. Why? If the size is available, then it's easy to calculate the final size as well.

**Q6: `.filter()` loses *IMMUTABLE, NONNULL***

Just notice that this operations loses as well *SUBSIZED, IMMUTABLE, NONNULL, SIZED*. It make sense to lose *SUBSIZED and SIZED*, but the others two doesn't make sense. Why?

---

I will appreciate if someone that understands deeply the spliterator could bring some clarity. Thanks.

Comment: Somebody voted to close the question as "too broad" and I was tempted to do the same because it looks like six questions in one. On the other hand, it is possible that there's an overall explanation for all of these details...

Comment: @Nicolai I voted initially... but it's too good to be closed, so I re-tracted it. I like this "all-in-one" for such a good question. Besides a few Oracle users (Stuart? or Brian?), I am only expecting Holger to know the exact intrinsic of these. Eagerly waiting. :)

Comment: *I understand that `.mapToObj()` can lose the NONNULL, IMMUTABLE and DISTI[N]CT*. Why not SORTED?

Comment: @shmosel good point! Did not think about it that is can potentially break the sort. Nice!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I have to admit that I had difficulties too when I first tried to find out the actual meaning of the characteristics and had the feeling that their meaning was not clearly settled during the implementation phase of Java 8 and is used inconsistently for that reason.

Consider [`Spliterator.IMMUTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#IMMUTABLE):

> Characteristic value signifying that the element source cannot be structurally modified; that is, elements cannot be added, replaced, or removed, so such changes cannot occur during traversal.

It’s strange to see “replaced” in this list, which is usually not considered a structural modification when speaking of a `List` or an array and consequently, stream and spliterator factories accepting an array (that is not cloned) report `IMMUTABLE`, like `LongStream.of(…)` or `Arrays.spliterator(long[])`.

If we interpret this more generously as “as long as not observable by the client”, there is no significant difference to `CONCURRENT`, as in either case *some* elements will be reported to the client without any way to recognize whether they were added during traversal or whether some were unreported due to removal, as there is no way to rewind a spliterator and compare.

The specification continues:

> A Spliterator that does not report `IMMUTABLE` or `CONCURRENT` is expected to have a documented policy (for example throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`) concerning structural interference detected during traversal.

And that’s the only relevant thing, a spliterator reporting either, `IMMUTABLE` or `CONCURRENT`,  is guaranteed to never throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Of course, `CONCURRENT` precludes `SIZED` semantically, but that has no consequence to the client code.

In fact, these characteristics are not used for anything in the Stream API, hence, using them inconsistently would never get noticed somewhere.

This is also the explanation why *every* intermediate operation has the effect of clearing the `CONCURRENT`, `IMMUTABLE` and `NONNULL` characteristics: the Stream implementation doesn’t use them and its internal classes representing the stream state do not maintain them.

---

Likewise, `NONNULL` is not used anywhere, so it’s absence for certain streams has no effect. I could track down the `LongStream.of(…)` issue down to the internal use of `Arrays.spliterator(long[], int, int)` which delegates to
[`Spliterators.spliterator​(long[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex, int additionalCharacteristics)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.html#spliterator-long:A-int-int-int-):

> The returned spliterator always reports the characteristics `SIZED` and `SUBSIZED`. The caller may provide additional characteristics for the spliterator to report. (For example, if it is known the array will not be further modified, specify `IMMUTABLE`; if the array data is considered to have an encounter order, specify `ORDERED`). The method `Arrays.spliterator(long[], int, int)` can often be used instead, which returns a spliterator that reports `SIZED`, `SUBSIZED`, `IMMUTABLE`, and `ORDERED`.

Note (again) the inconsistent use of the `IMMUTABLE` characteristic. It is again treated like having to guaranty the absence of any modification, while at the same time, `Arrays.spliterator` and in turn `Arrays.stream` and `LongStream.of(…)` will report the `IMMUTABLE` characteristic, even by specification, without being able to guaranty that the caller won’t modify their array. Unless we consider setting an element not to be a structural modification, but then, the entire distinction becomes nonsensical again, as arrays can’t be structurally modified.

And it clearly specified no `NONNULL`characteristic. While it is obvious that primitive values can’t be `null`, and the `Spliterator.Abstract<Primitive>Spliterator` classes invariably inject a `NONNULL` characteristic, the spliterator returned by `Spliterators.spliterator​(long[],int,int,int)` does not inherit from `Spliterator.AbstractLongSpliterator`.

The bad thing is, this can’t be fixed without changing the specification, the good thing is, it has no consequences anyway.

---

So if we ignore any issues with `CONCURRENT`, `IMMUTABLE`, or `NONNULL`, which have no consequences, we have

`SIZED` and `skip` & `limit`. This is a well known issue, result of the way `skip` and `limit` have been implemented by the Stream API. Other implementations are imaginable. This also applies to the combination of an infinite stream with a `limit`, which should have a predictable size, but given the current implementation, has not.

Combining `Stream.concat(…)` with `Stream.empty()`. It sounds reasonable that an empty stream does *not* impose constraints on the result order. But `Stream.concat(…)`’s behavior of releasing the order when only one input has no order, is questionable. Note that being too aggressive regarding ordering is nothing new, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28259636/2711488) regarding a behavior that was considered intentional first, but then has been fixed as late as Java 8, update 60. Perhaps, `Stream.concat` should have been discussed right at this point of time too…

The behavior of `.boxed()` is easy to explain. When it has been implemented naively like `.mapToObj(Long::valueOf)`, it will simply loose all the knowledge, as `mapToObj` can not assume that the result is still sorted or distinct. But this has been fixed with Java 9. There, `LongStream.range(0,10).boxed()` has `SUBSIZED|SIZED|ORDERED|SORTED|DISTINCT` characteristics, maintaining all characteristics that have relevance to the implementation.

Comment: Thank you @Holger. It's a bit awkward having so many characteristics that are not maintained. However if the majority it's for *englishman to see* (Portuguese expression that mens it's just for show off), then less problematic. I agreed that the problematic issues is when using `Stream.concat` with `Stream.empty`. And the second one is the Unsized Streams with `limit` or `skip` which was discussed in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547519/most-efficient-way-to-get-the-last-element-of-a-stream/46562493#46562493.

Comment: [http://richardstartin.uk/spliterator-characteristics-and-performance/](http://richardstartin.uk/spliterator-characteristics-and-performance/)this link also helps