# Spliterator SORTED characteristic behaviour

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, spliterator

[Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) interface defines a number of characteristics:

> A Spliterator also reports a set of characteristics() of its structure, source, and elements from among ORDERED, DISTINCT, SORTED, SIZED, NONNULL, IMMUTABLE, CONCURRENT, and SUBSIZED.

Let's have a look at [Sliterator#SORTED](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#SORTED)

> Characteristic value signifying that encounter order follows a defined sort order.

Now let's have a look at some examples:

```
List.of(1,2,3,4,5).stream().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED)
$1 ==> false
```

the stream is not sorted, so `Spliterator.SORTED` should be `false`.

Let's sort the stream:

```
List.of(1,2,3,4,5).stream().sorted().spliterator()
                           .hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED)
$2 ==> true
```

The stream is sorted, `Spliterator.SORTED` should be `true`, no surprises here.

Let's finally sort the stream, but using a custom `Comparator`.

```
List.of(1,2,3,4,5).stream().sorted((a,b) -> a.compareTo(b))
                  .spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED)
$3 ==> false
```

And I am completely lost here. Why `Spliterator.SORTED` is `false` in this case? The stream is sorted by with a custom comparator: `.sorted((a,b) -> a.compareTo(b))`, but `SORTED` flag is `false`. This seems illogical to me.

Let's image the following situation:

```
  List.of(1,2,3,4).stream()
1:                .sorted() // SORTED flag is set to true
2:                .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0) // Operation which doesn't reset SORTED
3:                .sorted() // can be ignored
4:                .forEach(System.out::println)
```

there are 3 intermediate operations in the stream pipeline: two `sorted` and `filter`. On line `1:` stream is sorted, on line `2:` the stream is filtered and  `Spliterator.SORTED` is still `true`. This means that on the `sorted` operation on line `3:` can be ignored (has been already sorted on line `1` and `SORTED` flag is true.

However when `sorted` with comparator is used -> **every** call to sorted will be executed even if compatator is the same:

```
List.of(1,2,3,4).stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) // SORTED flag is not affected
                .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) // will be sorted one more time
                .forEach(System.out::println)
```

It might be that I misunderstood the javadocs, but still this seems strange and illogical.

Comment: this is an exact duplicate of the answer I already gave btw :) thus deleted my answer

Comment: just be sure to read the comments! that `Spliterator#getComparator` last comment...

Comment: @Eugene, thanks a lot. Still this is a bit strange. I am curious if this will be changed in the future java releases.

Comment: well, I am not the person to ask this :| but yes, I am very interested also

Comment: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649315/2711488) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46712958/2711488), when you request a spliterator from a stream with intermediate operations, .i.e don't get the source spliterator, you will get a wrapper spliterator which will convert the stream state flags to characteristics, but the pipeline nodes only maintain flags the implementation actively uses. And sorted with custom comparator is not used. All other characteristics are lost.