# Is the skip() method a short circuiting-operation?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, short-circuiting

I am reading about Java streams' short-circuiting operations and found in some articles that `skip()` is a short-circuiting operation.

In another article they didn't mention `skip()` as a short-circuiting operation.

Now I am confused; is `skip()` a short-circuiting operation or not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[From the java doc under the "Stream operations and pipelines" section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)  :

> **An
>   intermediate operation is short-circuiting if, when presented with
>   infinite input, it may produce a finite stream as a result**. A terminal
>   operation is short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input,
>   it may terminate in finite time.

Emphasis mine.

if you were to call `skip` on an infinite input it won't produce a finite stream hence not a short-circuiting operation.

The only short-circuiting intermediate operation in *JDK8* is `limit` as it allows computations on infinite streams to complete in finite time.

**Example:**

if you were to execute this program with the use of `skip`:

```
String[] skip = Stream.generate(() -> "test") // returns an infinite stream
                      .skip(20) 
                      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

it will not produce a *finite* stream hence you would eventually end up with something along the lines of "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

whereas if you were to execute this program with the use of `limit`, it will cause the computation to finish in a `finite` time:

```
String[] limit = Stream.generate(() -> "test") // returns an infinite stream
                       .limit(20)
                       .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: there's one more besides `limit`, here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51575391/1059372

Comment: @Eugene `limit` is the only one in _jdk8_ which is what the question is tagged with. I guess I'll make it more clear by stating this in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Just want to add my two cents here, this idea *in general* of a short-circuiting a stream is infinitely complicated (at least to me and at least in the sense that I have to scratch my head twice usually). I will get to `skip` at the end of the answer btw.

Let's take this for example:

```
Stream.generate(() -> Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

This is an infinite stream, we can all agree on this. Let's short-circuit it via an operation that is *documented to be as such* (unlike `skip`):

```
Stream.generate(() -> Integer.MAX_VALUE).anyMatch(x -> true);
```

This works nicely, how about adding a `filter`:

```
Stream.generate(() -> Integer.MAX_VALUE)
      .filter(x -> x < 100) // well sort of useless...
      .anyMatch(x -> true);
```

What will happen here? Well, this never finishes, even if there is a short-circuiting operation like `anyMatch` - but it's never reached to actually short-circuit anything.

On the other hand, `filter` is *not* a short-circuiting operation, but you can make it as such (just as an example):

```
someList.stream()
        .filter(x -> {
           if(x > 3) throw AssertionError("Just because");            
})
```

Yes, it's ugly, but it's short-circuiting... That's how we (emphases on we, since *lots* of people, disagree) implement `short-circuiting reduce` - throw an Exception that has no stack traces.

In `java-9` there was an addition of another intermediate operation that is short-circuiting: `takeWhile` that acts sort of like `limit` but for a certain condition.

And to be fair, the bulk of the answer about `skip` was an already give by Aomine, but the most simple answer is that *it is not documented as such*. And in general (there are cases when documentation is corrected), but that is the number one indication you should look at. See `limit` and `takeWhile` for example that clearly says:

> This is a short-circuiting stateful intermediate operation

Comment: when you say "the most simple answer is that it is not documented as such". as well as that being true, I believe the quote of _"An intermediate operation is short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input, it may produce a finite stream, as a result"_ is more than enough for me. +1

Comment: @Aomine you are right, problem is that this is package documentation and considering how badly that is handled in IDE's usually, it is read on sparsely. You usually read only the method documentation itself

Comment: I guess I consider myself one of those people who always read the package documentation first before moving on to the method documentation. That said, being more explicit in the method doc would also make things a little bit better for some people I guess. remember this post a while back we answered on [iterator() on parallel stream guarantee encounter order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195495/iterator-on-parallel-stream-guarantee-encounter-order/48217564#48217564), you had to look really deep to find the answer only until Stuart Marks to say it was an oversight in the specification

Comment: I don't mean to spam the chat :), but where I said "you had to look really deep" should really have been "one had to look really deep" as I wasn't referring to you but rather the people in general.

Comment: @Aomine I did not even notice (or care) to begin with... all good!

Comment: @Aomine well, there are a lot of underspecified things, especially with the Stream API and still, to many people did not read the package documentation or even the class documentation. But to be fair to those developers, I have the strong feeling that the javadoc maintainers do not assume that anyone is still reading these awful frameset-html pages, especially after the introduction of modules, it’s an unnavigable mess and even internal links are often broken and no-one seems to care…