# IntStream iterate function with filter

Tags: java, filter, java-stream, intstream

I was reading this book called [Modern Java in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/modern-java-in-action) and one part of code I could not comprehend.

```
      IntStream.iterate(0, n -> n + 4)
                .filter(n -> n < 100)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Authors says that code will not terminate. 
The reason is that there’s no way to know in the filter that the numbers continue to increase, so it keeps on filtering them infinitely!

I did not get the reason. Could someone explain it why.

Comment: why is this post closed? the question is clear... OP wants more clarity on "why does this stream not terminate"

Comment: @Rakesh - Could you elaborate, which part in the specified reason did you not understand?

Comment: That’s actually a bad example, as the `int` value will overflow (very soon in up-to-date environments) and loop through the `int` data range forever. It should be clear that skipping the `[100‑Integer.MAX_VALUE]` range will not change the infinite nature of the iteration. A better example would be `Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ZERO, n -> n.add(BigInteger.TWO)) .filter(n -> n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(100)) < 0) .forEach(System.out::println);`. But even `IntStream.generate(() -> 42) .filter(n -> false) .forEach(System.out::println);` will loop forever, despite not having any perceivable result.

Comment: @Holger: My intension is to ask why it doesn't stop and I believe this example is good enough.

Comment: But why should it stop? The source stream is infinite and `filter` only tells to skip nonmatching elements. The only reason to assume that it could stop, would be the assumption that no elements can occur after crossing the `n < 100` threshold. And that would be flat wrong as keeping on incrementing the `int` value will overflow and there *are* elements after crossing the threshold. When it comes to the Stream API, my `BigInteger` example will illustrate the issue better, as it shows that even if there truly will be no elements after crossing the threshold, the Stream will keep on testing.

Answer (score 1):

> Authors says that code will not terminate.

Yes, because this specific overload of [`iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-)

```
static IntStream iterate(int seed,
                         IntUnaryOperator f)
```

> Returns an infinite sequential ordered IntStream produced by iterative
>   application of a function f to an initial element seed, producing a
>   Stream consisting of seed, f(seed), f(f(seed)), etc.

returns an infinite stream and given it's an infinite stream it means it can only be terminated via certain operations.

Given the terminal operation in use here (`forEach`) is not short-circuiting it means that you require a "short-circuiting intermediate operation" to truncate the infinite stream in this specific case e.g. `limit` (JDK8),`takeWhile` (JDK9) et al.

The only [short-circuiting intermediate operation in JDK8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571912/is-the-skip-method-a-short-circuiting-operation/51571997#51571997) is `limit` as it allows computations on infinite streams to complete in finite time.

> The reason is that there’s no way to know in the filter that the
>   numbers continue to increase, so it keeps on filtering them
>   infinitely!

`filter` itself is not a short-circuiting intermediate operation hence cannot terminate a stream. `filter`'s job is essentially to return a stream consisting of the elements of the stream that match the given predicate.

Conclusion: if one is using an infinite stream which does not have a short-circuiting terminal operation then it requires a short-circuiting intermediate operation to truncate the stream else the stream remains infinite.

Comment: nice explanation Ousmane. I got the point why it is not terminating.

Answer (score 0):

The int stream will generate a sequence of numbers that start from 0 and have step of 4. Then they will be filtered out. The Int keep generating because there is no terminal condition. It equivalent to

```
for(int n=0;;n=n+4){... Filter out }
```