# How to deserialize the String which is array of objects to a array of objects?

Tags: java, json

I have a response Body

```
[{"vendorName":"ABC","vendorAPI":"Some_API","enrichmentGroupingLevel":[{"Test":{"score":0.233,"risckscore":229},"level":"all"}],"error":{},"statusCode":200}]",
CoreV2Response[] getEnrichmentResponse = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, CoreV2Response[].class);
```

The below is my coreV2Response class which i want to map with

```
public class CoreV2Response {
            @JsonProperty("vendorName")
            private String vendorName;
            @JsonProperty("vendorAPI")
            private String vendorAPI;
            @JsonProperty("enrichmentGroupingLevel")
            private Object[] enrichmentGroupingLevel;
            @JsonProperty("error")
            private Object[] error;
            @JsonProperty("statusCode")
            private int statusCode;
        }
```

````
I am getting error 
Cannot deserialize instance of [Ljava.lang.Object; out of START_OBJECT tokenat [Source: (String)"[{"vendorName":"Ekata","vendorAPI":"Account_Opening_V1.0","enrichmentGroupingLevel
```
 
Can someone help me with deserialization?
I have added my both the codes for response template class and mapper object
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your json string error is in object

```
"error": {}
```

But in CoreV2Response you have declared the `error` field as object array:

```
private Object[] error;
```

You cannot deserialize json object into collection, array in your case. You have to declare error as an object

```
private Object error;
```

And deserialization goes without problems.

Comment: Can i access each variable in the class by getEnrichmentResponse.getvendorName like this?

Comment: @krishnagiri2000 I'm not sure i understand the question. If you are asking how to access data in error, since the field is declared as `Object` it is deserialized as a `Map<String, Object>`, so you need to cast in to a Map and use methods provided by map to access data in it.

Comment: Is i am calling the method of object mapper class correctly , considering the response body is an string which is an array of objects?

Comment: @krishnagiri2000 Yes, calling object mapper like this - `CoreV2Response[] getEnrichmentResponse = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, CoreV2Response[].class);` is absolutely correct in your case. The only error was what i wrote in the answear, everything else is correct.

Comment: like in my case  the enrichmentGroupingLevel is array of objects, so I can cast this to a list of object right so it will be like - List<Object> newParams = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(getEnrichmentResponse[0].getEnrichmentGroupingLevel()));      FYI-getEnrichmentGroupingLevel is my getter methof for getEnrichmentResponse

Comment: @krishnagiri2000 Yes, thats one of the ways to do it, and it is a correct one.

Comment: Now in the above case i will get enrichmentGroupingLevel by getEnrichmentReponse[0].getEnrichmentGroupingLevel() which will be array of objects ...Now It is an array containing objects so i want to fetch the first object out of it , how can i do it?

Comment: @krishnagiri2000 [how to get first/last element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860739/how-to-get-first-and-last-element-in-an-array-in-java/39860854)

Comment: Is there any way to manipulate with object in java or i have to convert it to hashmap and then use hashmap methodds? Lets say  I have to replace a value for particular key then it would be simple in  hashmap but in object we cannot do it

Comment: @krishnagiri2000 That should be a separate question altogether.