# Set object in lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

how could I set my object to another in lambda expression? I got error

> variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final

with following code:

```
public MyObj myFun(MyObj o) {
   MyObj obj = null;

   myObjList.stream().filter(o -> ...).forEach(o -> {
      // I do some stuff here

      // I need here set obj to o, but I got error
      obj = o;
   });

   return myObj; // I need return found obj or null;
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to find the last object in the list that matches the condition?  If so, this could be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21426843).

Comment: You should use a collector.

Comment: no you are not allowed to do this in Java. state your actual end goal.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem no, I am looking for some specific object in list, and next do some operations with that object, and on the end, set its to variable which I return, or variable stay null;

Comment: @DenisStephanov ok, but what should happen if there are multiple Elements that match your filter? Should it just use the first one? Or anyone?

Comment: that is not possible because I filter by unique id.

Comment: @DenisStephanov you’re looking for findFirst.

Comment: @Aominè I think he wants `obj` to end up being the _last_ object that matches the condition, not the _first_.  Unless, of course, there's only one such object; but he hasn't stated this.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem  OP said “ I filter by unique Id” ;)

Comment: But how this solve my problem? I need do operations with founded object, also update some values in this object, and on the end set it into variable which I return on the on of function, but I can't due to error.

Comment: "Effectively final" mean that your code should work if you actually added the "final" keyword to the variable.  Setting it violates this requirement.

Comment: @Aominè  Ooh, you're right.  I missed that.  So `findFirst` would be a really good solution then.  Frankly though, if I were writing this, I'd use a good old for-each loop and an if statement.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen for a variable to be effectively final it need not be declared final rather it needs not be reassigned after being assigned the first time.

Comment: @Aominè Would "should _still_ work" be better.  The whole point of "effectively final" is that the variable is used as if it was declared final.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign `o` to the outer variable. But you can return it as a result of you stream processing. Use `map` instead of `forEach` and return `o` from the mapper. Then do `findAny` or `findFirst` - this will give you an `Optional<MyObj>`. Finally do `orElse(null)` to return the found and processed object or `null` if none was found.

```
MyObj obj = myObjList
   .stream()
   .filter(o -> ...)
   .map(o -> {
       // I do some stuff here

       // I need here set obj to o, but I got error
       return o;
   })
   .findAny()
   .orElse(null);
```

Comment: to OP - if the logic inside “map” is more than 2-3 lines I’d extract it into another method and call that from “map”.

Comment: No harm using findAny but that’s more used when performing Parallel processing.

Comment: Thans for answer, but in "some stuff" I also need update founded object, and after update return it.

Comment: @Aominè What's "patel processing"?

Comment: @DenisStephanov So what's the problem? Update it, return it.

Comment: Oh yes, you right, sorry my bad. I'll check this as answer, thanks.

Comment: Whatever updates you need to do to the object can be done _after_ you've finished trawling through the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `forEach` instead consider using `map(o->{...}).findFirst().get()`  (or similar depending on your logic if no item is relevant - your `null` case).

In general, you should let streams finish in a collector or a selector (findFirst/findAny etc.) because that will allow you to write simpler and clearer code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of streaming through it, you could simply iterate through it in a loop and then return the value when you find it.

The streamy sort of answer is probably to use something like [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--).