# Changing a Goolge's Place object inside a lambda

Tags: java, android

I want to get a `Place` object from the Google Places API in an app I build in android studio.
I'm using this code to do so:

```
List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.OPENING_HOURS);
        FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(chosenPlaceId, placeFields);
        final PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this); 
        placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
            Place chosenPlace = response.getPlace();
            ...
```

I want to use the returned Place object, but I couldn't get it outside the lambda scope. I've seen some suggested [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022628/set-object-in-lambda-expression), but I couldn't make them work in my case.
Is there a simple non-hacky way of doing that?

Thanks.