# Guava's Streams::findLast implementation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, guava

I am looking into the implementation of `Streams::findLast` from Guava and while trying to understand it, there were a couple of things that simply I could not grasp. Here is it's implementation:

```
public static <T> java.util.Optional<T> findLast(Stream<T> stream) {
    class OptionalState {

        boolean set = false;
        T value = null;

        void set(@Nullable T value) {
            set = true;
            this.value = value;
        }

        T get() {
            checkState(set);
            return value;
        }
    }
    OptionalState state = new OptionalState();

    Deque<Spliterator<T>> splits = new ArrayDeque<>();
    splits.addLast(stream.spliterator());

    while (!splits.isEmpty()) {
        Spliterator<T> spliterator = splits.removeLast();

        if (spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0) {
            continue; // drop this split
        }

        // Many spliterators will have trySplits that are SUBSIZED even if they are not themselves
        // SUBSIZED.
        if (spliterator.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SUBSIZED)) {
            // we can drill down to exactly the smallest nonempty spliterator
            while (true) {
                Spliterator<T> prefix = spliterator.trySplit();
                if (prefix == null || prefix.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0) {
                    break;
                } else if (spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0) {
                    spliterator = prefix;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // spliterator is known to be nonempty now
            spliterator.forEachRemaining(state::set);
            return java.util.Optional.of(state.get());
        }

        Spliterator<T> prefix = spliterator.trySplit();
        if (prefix == null || prefix.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0) {
            // we can't split this any further
            spliterator.forEachRemaining(state::set);
            if (state.set) {
                return java.util.Optional.of(state.get());
            }
            // fall back to the last split
            continue;
        }
        splits.addLast(prefix);
        splits.addLast(spliterator);
    }
    return java.util.Optional.empty();
}
```

In essence the implementation is not that complicated to be honest, but here are the things that I find a bit weird (and I'll take the blame here if this question gets closed as "opinion-based", I understand it might happen).

---

**First** of all is the creation of `OptionalState` class, this could have been replaced with an array of a single element:

```
T[] state = (T[]) new Object[1];
```

and used as simple as:

```
spliterator.forEachRemaining(x -> state[0] = x);
```

Then the entire method could be split into 3 pieces:

1. when a certain Spliterator is known to be empty:

   if (spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0)

In this case it's easy - just drop it.

2. then if the Spliterator is known to be `SUBSIZED`. This is the "happy-path" scenario; as in this case we can split this until we get to the last element. Basically the implementation says: split until the `prefix` is either `null` or it's empty (in which case consume the "right" spliterator) or if after a split the "right" spliterator is known to be empty, consume the `prefix` one. This is done via:

   // spliterator is known to be nonempty now
   spliterator.forEachRemaining(state::set);
   return java.util.Optional.of(state.get());

**Second** question I have is actually about this comment:

```
// Many spliterators will have trySplits that are SUBSIZED 
// even if they are not themselves SUBSIZED.
```

This is very interesting, but I could not find such an example, would appreciate if someone would introduce me to one. As a matter of fact, because this comment exists, the code in the next (3-rd part of the method can not be done with a `while(true)` like the second), because it assumes that after a `trySplit` we could obtain a `Spliterator` that is `SUBSIZED`, even if our initial one was not, so it has to go to the very beginning of `findLast`.

3. this part of the method is when a Spliterator is known *not* to be `SUBSIZED` and in this case it does not have a known size; thus it relies on how the Spliterator from the source is implemented and in this case actually a `findLast` makes little sense... for example a `Spliterator` from a `HashSet` will return whatever the last entry is in the last bucket...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. When you iterate a `Spliterator` of an unknown size, you have to track whether an element has been encountered. This can be done by calling `tryAdvance` and using the return value or by using `forEachRemaining` with a `Consumer` which records whether an element has been encountered. When you go the latter route, a dedicated class is simpler than an array. And once you have a dedicated class, why not use it for the `SIZED` spliterator as well.

   What’s strange to me, is that this local class, which only exists to be used as a `Consumer`, doesn’t implement `Consumer` but requires the binding via `state::set`.
2. Consider

   ```
   Stream.concat(
       Stream.of("foo").filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()),
       Stream.of("bar", "baz"))
   ```

   The `Spliterator` representing the entire stream can’t have the `SIZED` characteristic. But when splitting off the first substream with the unknown size, the remaining stream has a known size.

   Test code:

   ```
   Spliterator<String> sp = Stream.concat(
       Stream.of("foo").filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()),
       Stream.of("bar", "baz"))
       .spliterator();
   do {
       System.out.println(
             "SIZED: "+sp.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SIZED)
           + ", SUBSIZED: "+sp.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SUBSIZED)
           + ", exact size if known: "+sp.getExactSizeIfKnown());
   } while(sp.trySplit() != null);
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   SIZED: false, SUBSIZED: false, exact size if known: -1
   SIZED: true, SUBSIZED: true, exact size if known: 2
   SIZED: true, SUBSIZED: true, exact size if known: 1
   ```

   But to me, it looks weird when someone tells in a comment to know that splitting can change the characteristics and then doing a pre-test with `SUBSIZED`, instead of just doing the split and check whether the result has a known size. After all, the code is doing the split anyway, in the alternative branch, when the characteristic is not present. In [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27548268/2711488), I did the pretest to avoid allocating data structures, but here, the `ArrayDeque` is always created and used. But I think, even my old answer could be simplified.
3. I’m not sure what you are aiming at. When a `Spliterator` has the `ORDERED` characteristic, the order of traversal and splitting is well-defined. Since `HashSet` is not ordered, the term “last” is meaningless. If you are radical, you could optimize the operation to just return the first element for unordered streams; that’s valid and much faster.

   What is strange, is this condition:

   ```
   if (prefix == null || prefix.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0) {
       // we can't split this any further
   ```

   (and a similar loop termination in the `SUBSIZED` path)

   Just because one prefix happened to have a known zero size, it does not imply that the suffix can’t split further. Nothing in the specification says that.

   As a consequence of this condition, `Stream.concat(Stream.of("foo"), Stream.of("bar","baz"))` can be handled optimally, whereas for `Stream.concat(Stream.of(), Stream.of("bar", "baz"))`, it will fall back to a traversal, because the first prefix has a known size of zero.