# Convert iterative method to functional with Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this algorithm right here,

```
    while ((start + end) / 2 != 0) {
        Double mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (Math2.pow(mid, 3) < n) {
            start = mid;
        } else if (Math.abs(n - Math2.pow(mid, 3)) > Math2.pow(e, 3)) {
            end = mid;
        } else if (Math.abs(n - Math2.pow(mid, 3)) < Math2.pow(e, 3)) {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return 0.0;

}
```

that gives me the cubic root of n with a loss precision of e. I need to do the same thing but using Java 8 Streams. Math2 is from a private git rep. You can use Math.pow instead; it will work too. How can I do the same algorithm with Streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Stream API has method [`Stream::iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) starting from Java 9, therefore a class representing the iteration steps/states may be implemented as follows:

```java
class CubeSolver {
    static final double EPS = 1E-06;
        
    private double start, end, n, mid;

    public CubeSolver(double s, double e, double n) {
        this.start = s;
        this.end = e;
        this.n = n;
        this.mid = (start + end) / 2;
    }

    // UnaryOperator<CubeSolver> for iteration
    public CubeSolver next() {
        if (done()) {
            return this;
        }
        if (Math.pow(mid, 3) < n) {
            start = mid;
        } else if (Math.abs(n - Math.pow(mid, 3)) > EPS) {
            end = mid;
        }
        return new CubeSolver(start, end, n);
    }
    
    // define end of calculation
    public boolean done() {
        return mid == 0 || Math.abs(n - Math.pow(mid, 3)) < EPS;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "root = " + mid;
    }
}
```

Then the stream-based solution looks like this:

1. define an initial seed with `start`, `end`, `n`
2. use `Stream::iterate` with `hasNext` predicate to create a *finite* stream
   2a) or use older `Stream::iterate` without `hasNext` but with [`Stream::takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) operation to conditionally limit the stream - also available since Java 9
3. use `Stream::reduce` [to get the last element of the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426843/get-last-element-of-stream-list-in-a-one-liner)

```java
CubeSolver seed = new CubeSolver(1.8, 2.8, 8);
CubeSolver solution = Stream
    .iterate(seed, cs -> !cs.done(), CubeSolver::next)
    .reduce((first, last) -> last) // Optional<CubeSolver>
    .orElse(null);
    
System.out.println(solution);
```

Output:

```
root = 2.0000002861022947
```

In Java 11 static [`Predicate::not`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)) was added, so the 2a solution using `takeWhile` could look like this:

```java
CubeSolver seed = new CubeSolver(0, 7, 125);
CubeSolver solution = Stream
    .iterate(seed, CubeSolver::next)
    .takeWhile(Predicate.not(CubeSolver::done))
    .reduce((first, last) -> last) // Optional<CubeSolver>
    .orElse(null);
    
System.out.println(solution);
```

Output (for EPS = 1E-12):

```
root = 4.999999999999957
```