# How to adjust tax to some tax rate

Tags: java

In my application I have some List with tax rates getTaxRates().
The problem is that user can put some value which should not be possible.
That means tax rates can be taken only from this list E.g. 7%, 9% and 21% and if user puts 7.5% then it should be saved 9%, if he puts 4% then 7%.
The problem is the tax rate is flexible and I don't know what is the value- it can the list of 5 values e.g. 2%, 5%, 19%, 21% or 5%, 9%, 16%. How to implement this condition?

For know I have only the method which can see if the value is in range but no clue how to implement the condition checking the values which will come later from the user of my application settings.

```
private static boolean inRange(List<Integer> list, int min, int max) {
    return list.stream().allMatch(i -> i >= min && i <= max);
}
```

Comment: Why not just give the user a drop-down menu?  If that's not possible for some odd reason, what rules are you following based on user input?  Round up to the nearest acceptable value?

Comment: This must come from backend logic because there are some countries where you can put 3,4% and dropdown would be a big problem

Comment: Yes but idea is that you have some application manager or person who can put allowed tax rates and on the other side the user who can put product with some wrong tax rate. And here I need to validate it to put only the correct tax in tax rate list.

Comment: I don't want to have responsibility with allowed taxes and this is forwarded to some admin user who can determine allowed tax rate. This is the point of this :) It must come from backend

Comment: Ok, but it sounds like you'd still need the rules to follow.  Are you always rounding up if the input is in between tax brackets that you are given?  Or are you throwing an exception?

Comment: Yes the rule is that rounding is up to 0.5% e.g. and if the user takes 3,6% then it will be taken the nearest highest rate from the list getTaxRates(). If there are 3 values like {3%,4%,17%} then the 4% is the correct one.

Comment: Tax rates are grouped with conditional names (A, B, C, D ...) and the user chooses from them (he does not work with the real value). In the application, an administrative panel is created in which rates are allowed/disallowed and their real value is set. The conditional group (required) + the value is recorded in the history data (records in the database).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem.

Here is one possible way using a `List` and `BigDecimal` to get you started:

```
public static BigDecimal findRate(List<BigDecimal> allowedRates, BigDecimal inputRate) {
    return allowedRates.stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparing(a -> inputRate.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                    .subtract(a).abs()))
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

Here is a sample Junit 5 test.  You can check to see whether your particular requirements are met.

```
List<BigDecimal> ALLOWED_RATES = List.of(new BigDecimal("7.0"),
        new BigDecimal("9.0"),
        new BigDecimal("21.0"));

@ParameterizedTest(name = "#{index}: Testing {0}")
@DisplayName("Find the appropriate tax rate")
@CsvSource({
        "7.0, 7.0",
        "9.0, 9.0",
        "21.0, 21.0",
        "10.0, 9.0",
        "16.0, 21.0",
        "22.0, 21.0",
        "0, 7.0"
})
public void testFindTaxRate(BigDecimal input, BigDecimal expected) {
    BigDecimal actual = MyTaxRateCalculator.findRate(ALLOWED_RATES, input);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

In your production code, the method doesn't need to be static.  It does make this unit test a little less verbose for this answer.

You may wish to sort, remove duplicates, or perform error-checking as needed based on your requirements on your allowed tax rate list.  This method will also work fine if you use change the implementation from a `List` to a `Set` that maintains order if that works better for you.  Using a `Set` is really nice, but it tends to require changes elsewhere in the system, and sometimes many IMO.

Finally, be careful which [type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) you use for this.

**UPDATE:**

If you are looking to always choose the higher bracket given a choice between the two nearest values in your allowed list, then your code could become something like:

```
public static BigDecimal findRate(List<BigDecimal> allowedRates, BigDecimal inputRate) {

    BigDecimal lastBracket = allowedRates.stream().reduce((a, b) -> b).orElse(null);
    if (inputRate.compareTo(lastBracket) >= 0) {
        return lastBracket;
    }

    return allowedRates.stream()
            .filter(rate -> rate.compareTo(inputRate) >= 0)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

And your test could be:

```
List<BigDecimal> ALLOWED_RATES = List.of(new BigDecimal("7.0"),
     new BigDecimal("9.0"),
     new BigDecimal("21.0"));

@ParameterizedTest(name = "#{index}: testing {0}")
@DisplayName("Find the appropriate tax rate")
@CsvSource({
        "7.0, 7.0",
        "9.0, 9.0",
        "21.0, 21.0",
        "10.0, 21.0",
        "16.0, 21.0",
        "22.0, 21.0",
        "0, 7.0"
})
public void testFindRate(BigDecimal input, BigDecimal expected) {
    BigDecimal actual = MyTaxRateCalculator.findRate(ALLOWED_RATES, input);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: I think you're finding the nearest allowed rate to the one the user entered, but the OP wants the next highest one. E.g. if allowed rattes = 7, 9, 21, then if the user inputs 10 the result should be 21, not 9.

Comment: I was confused about that as well, and the reply was "Yes the rule is that rounding is up to 0.5%" so I took that to mean half-way given OP's example.

Comment: The OP is indeed unclear, but the example given as "E.g. 7%, 9% and 21% and if user puts 7.5% then it should be saved 9%" implies that it should be rounded up to the nearest allowed rate that is equal to or higher than the given rate. Otherwise, it would be 7% because that is nearer to the input 7.5%.

Comment: Good point.  Will revise

Comment: Can't `lastBracket = allowedRates.stream()...` be shortened to `lastBracket = allowedRates.get(allowedRates.size() - 1)`?

Comment: Yes, sure.  The other way just uses streams.  Other choices too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426843/get-last-element-of-stream-list-in-a-one-liner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252195/discussion-between-vphilipnyc-and-k314159).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TreeSet` for this kind of implementation. [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) provides `ceiling()` method. This method will return the least element in the set greater than or equal to the given element, or `null` if there is no such element.

Implementation:

```
private static Float getTaxRates(TreeSet<Float> taxRates, Float taxRate) {
    return taxRates.ceiling(taxRate);
}
```